# Does this simple way of writing multiple conditions on an if exist?

Tags: javascript, html

im doing a basic calculator to learn JS. Right now im making an if condition that if the button pressed is NOT a number, then do something. While i was writing it i wondered if there's a way of doing something like this (of course THIS exact sintaxys does not exist, i know that, but I think you'll understand what im looking for)

> if (buttonPressed.innerText != "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0")

or anything similar, so i can avoid doing writing:

> if (buttonPressed.innerText != "1" && buttonPressed.innerText != "2"  && buttonPressed.innerText != "3" , **etc**)

basically, an easier and faster way of writing multiple conditions to avoid such an extensive text. i tried googling this but since Spanish is my main language and not English i dont know how to formulate this question briefly to work on google. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `if (!"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0".includes(buttonPressed.innerText))` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: @ChrisG What are the commas for in this case? It’s just checking for a digit.

Comment: @DaveNewton True but I thought I'd use OP's string just to show how close they were.

Comment: also, how would you get a two or three digit number without them